# Isaiah 57:15 The Dakah and Shaphal

Tags: words, commentaries, isaiah-yeshaya-the-book

Isaiah 57:15 reads: ואת-דכא ושפל-רוח להחיות רוח שפלים ולהחיות לב נדכאים
Regards this part of the verse:

What do the terms דכא and שפל literally and figuratively mean? - There are so many different translations that it makes me wonder how they derived these meanings from these hebrew words - and why the term רוח is added to these two words?

Comment: Some tools to start with: http://www.sefaria.org/Isaiah.57.15?lang=bi&with=Commentary&lang2=en

Answer (score 1):

There's no definite article. *Daka* is "crushed", and *shafal* is "lowly." Thus, "anyone who is crushed or low of spirit."

Comment: so first 'the crushed and low of spirit׳ and second part 'low of spirit' and one with 'a crushed heart'? Does a crushed heart takes part when one has a crushed and low spirit? Or is this verse talking about two seperated things